# Application of Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f ∈ L^{1}([0, 1])$. Prove that $lim$ $ε→0^{+} \int_{[0,ε]} f dµ = 0$

My attempt at proof:

Let $B_N$ be an open ball of radius $N$ centred at origin.

$E_N:=$ {$x: f(x)\leq N$}

$f_N(x):=f(x) \chi_{E_N}$

$f_N$ is measurable. Also, $f_{N+1}\geq f_{N}$ and $lim _N\to \infty f_N(x)=f(x)$

By Monotone Convergence Theorem,

$lim _N\to \infty \int_{[0,1]} f_N d\mu=\ \int_{[0,1]} f d\mu$

$\implies 0\leq \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\ d\mu- \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\chi_{E_N}\ d\mu<\epsilon/2$ for some $\epsilon$

$\implies \int_{[0,1]} [f(x)-f_N(x)]\ d\mu<\epsilon/2$.

$\mu([0,\epsilon])=\epsilon$.

So, $\int_{[0,\epsilon]} f\ d\mu= \int_{[0,\epsilon]} [f-f_N]\ d\mu+\int_{[0,\epsilon]} f_N\ d\mu\leq \int_{[0,1]} [f-f_N]\ d\mu + \int_{[0,\epsilon]} f_N\ d\mu \leq \epsilon/2+N \epsilon$

Please suggest if the proof is correct.

Comment: first, you wnt to know what happens near 0. why are you taking a look at infinity? is at least $f$ defined near infinity?

Comment: @mookid: Can you please suggest a proof then? I was thinking to prove that the integral is always less than $\epsilon$

Comment: Apologies for the above comments. Some of the issues would be that Monotone convergence only applies to positive (or negative) functions, not general $L^1$ functions. Also, since your final bound contains $N$, you can't know how it will behave in the limit, so that the proof is not complete.

Comment: @WSL: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually I also saw that the final bound has $N$ and hence presented the proof here for refinement. Any suggestions on how to prove this then?

Comment: I suggest splitting $f$ up $f= f^+-f^-$ and starting with the assumption that you are dealing with a positive function. That way, monotone convergence is applicable and you can go from there.

Comment: @Silvermoon I did it. tell me if you have any more question.

Comment: @WSL: I am sorry for not writing $f=f^{+}- f^{-}$. But in fact, I was assuming in my solution that $f$ is positive

Comment: @mookid: Agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume $f\ge 0$.

Consider the sequence $f_\epsilon = f\times 1_{(0,\epsilon)}$. $f_\epsilon$ decreases when $\epsilon\to 0$ as $f\ge 0$, and $f_\epsilon (x) \to 0$ pointwise.

Applying the monotonic convergence theorem, you get
$$
\int_0^\epsilon fd\mu = \int f_\epsilon d\mu\to 0
$$

---

When $f\in L^1$, write $f = f^+ - f^-$ with $f^\pm \ge 0$. And apply the first part twice.

Comment: But how do we claim $f_\epsilon $ is sequence of measurable functions?

Comment: It is the product of measurable functions

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any of the convergence theorems. First, it's clear if $f$ is bounded. For the general $f\in L^1,$ let $t> 0.$ Then there is a simple function $s$ such that $\int_0^1|f-s|<t.$ Thus

$$\int_0^\epsilon|f| \le \int_0^\epsilon|f-s|+\int_0^\epsilon|s|< t + \int_0^\epsilon|s|.$$

This shows

$$\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\epsilon|f| \le t.$$

Since $t>0$ is arbitrary, we have the desired result.